# How do i navigate one page to another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i tried to navigate one page to another page but it didn't work.i used angularjs as front end.

My angularjs file is

```
var app = angular.module('loginApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // default route
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     // app routes
     $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
             url: '/tokken/s/',
             templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
             controller: 'loginCtrl'
         });

   });
  // Controller function and passing $http service and $scope var.
  app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
    // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.user = {};
    // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      // Posting data to  file
      $http.post('/tokken/login/', $scope.user).then(function (response) {
        //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-AUTH-TOKEN"] = response.data;
        if (response.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorName = response.errors.name;
          $scope.erroPassword = response.errors.password;
        } else {
           //$scope.message = response.data;
          $state.go('home');
        }
      });
    };

 // calling our submit function.
    $scope.regForm = function() {
      // Posting data to  file
      $http.post('/tokken/s/', $scope.user).then(function (response) {
        //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-AUTH-TOKEN"] = response.data;
        if (response.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorName = response.errors.name;
          $scope.erroPassword = response.errors.password;
        } else {
           $scope.message = response.data;

        }
      });
    };
  });  
/////////////
```

My html files is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="loginApp">
<head>

</head>
<body ng-controller="loginCtrl" ui-view="content">    

    <form  ng-submit="submitForm()">
      <br> user name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
      <br>
      <br> password:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.password">
      <br>    
      <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
<script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="/controller/login.js"></script>

<script src="/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

above code post a value. but didn't navigate to another page.
while i using $location provider in it. post didn't work. help me please

Comment: Did you check browser console? Any errors logged?

Comment: while using $location provider unable to post and  got http 403 error. when removing $location provider post is happened but can't redirect the page

Comment: can you provide a plunkr ?

Answer (score 2):

You should rather put the index contents into another template so that the state can return to "/" if the state changed, and because you set it as the default state:  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");`

Add this to your stateProvider:

```
.state('login', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
             controller: 'loginCtrl'
         });
```

Also since your state is already assigning a controller the `ng-controller="loginCtrl"` in the body tag does not belong there.

Comment: your code is simple enough to add to a plunkr, please do that so we can check it for you

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
    .state('home', {
        url: '/token/s',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
```

Instead of

```
 .state('home', {
     url: '/tokken/s/',
     templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
     controller: 'loginCtrl'
 });
```